# displaying text input and password input elements in the same line in IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Given the following simple code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="password">
</body>
</html>
```

and display the code in IE8 or IE9, we'll see the two input boxes are in the same line while with a very small difference of their vertical positions as shown below:
[image]

this bothered me a lot, how can i remove such difference?

Comment: By applying CSS styling, although it is weird they are different to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

empirically, ie9 developer tools says that the text input is 47.24 px wide by 15.33 px tall, with a 2px border; and the password is 40.68px wide by 16.09px tall, with a 2px border. as shown here

http://jsfiddle.net/Tp7FW/

You can apply

```
input {
     height:20px;
}
```

or something similar to get all your inputs to be the same size(height), as shown here
http://jsfiddle.net/Tp7FW/1/

Comment: Hi the solution does not work for my IE9, the height of a text input and a password input are identical. It's their vertical position that differs. I know this can be solved by "margin-top" while that's a stupid hack. There must be some better approach.

Comment: this solution was created with ie9.  looking at their developer tools yields that their heights are different unless explicitly stated